# Should I use a ARDL if I have more than one cointegrating relationship?

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model, ardl

I have a four time series variables. They are a mix of I(0) and I(1) variables. There is also more than one cointegrating relationship among the variables. If there is more than one cointegrating relationship among the variables, then should I use VECM rather than ARDL? Or, is there an alternative model that might better suit my purposes?

Answer (score 0):

I believe Pesaran et al. talks about this in their paper: BOUNDS TESTING APPROACHES TO THE ANALYSIS OF LEVEL RELATIONSHIPS, JOURNAL OF APPLIED ECONOMETRICS J. Appl. Econ. 16: 289–326 (2001) DOI: 10.1002/jae.616

The paper suggests that there can only be one long-run (co integrating) relationship.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! As it stands this is more of a comment than an answer - would you add just an outline of what the paper says? Or we can convert this to a comment.